# SqlAlchemy StaleDataError on simple update statement

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, orm

I'm trying to update a user in the database but keep running into a `StaleDataError`.

```
user = session.query(User).get(1)
user.first_name # John
user.first_name = 'Sally'
session.commit()

# > sqlalchemy.orm.exc.StaleDataError: UPDATE statement on table 'user' expected to update 1 row(s);
#   -1 were matched.
```

From the [SqlAlchemy docs](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/orm/exceptions.html#sqlalchemy.orm.exc.StaleDataError) on StaleDataError:

> An operation encountered database state that is unaccounted for.
>
> Conditions which cause this to happen include:
>
> A flush may have attempted to update or delete rows and an unexpected
> number of rows were matched during the UPDATE or DELETE statement.
> Note that when version_id_col is used, rows in UPDATE or DELETE
> statements are also matched against the current known version
> identifier.
>
> A mapped object with version_id_col was refreshed, and the version
> number coming back from the database does not match that of the object
> itself.
>
> A object is detached from its parent object, however the object was
> previously attached to a different parent identity which was garbage
> collected, and a decision cannot be made if the new parent was really
> the most recent “parent”.

The docs don't elaborate on `version_id_col`. Could this be the issue? What is this column and where can I find if it's active?

Why can't SqlAlchemy locate the row id (which is obviously there since it pulled the row just moments before) and what's wrong with my update command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution in [an answer by @tamersalama](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73041216/10753968). I'm reposting it here because that question was hard to find in connection to the StaleDataError.

Add `__mapper_args__` to the SqlAlchemy model:

```
class User(Base):

    __tablename__ = 'user'
    user_id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, nullable=False)
    first_name = Column(String(20))
    last_name = Column(String(20))

    __mapper_args__ = {
        'version_id_col': user_id, # this is the id column of the model
        'version_id_generator': False
    }
```